# (z*) * z + 4iz + 4i = 0, complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

$(z*) * z + 4iz + 4i = 0$

How to solve an equation like this? Substituting z with a + bi gives:

$z^2 + 4i(a+bi)+4i = 0$

$z^2+ 4ai - 4b + 4i = 0$

What to do next?

Comment: do you mean $$z^2+4iz+4i=0$$?

Comment: I think it you can write like that too yes

Comment: What does the $z*$ inside the parentheses mean? And what does the $*$ outside the parentheses mean?

Comment: Does $(z*)*z$ mean $\,\overline{\overline{z}} \cdot z\,$, or $\,\overline{z} \cdot z\,$ or ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solving the equation $$z^2+4iz+4i=0$$ we get $$z_1=-2i+2\sqrt{-1-i}$$ or $$z_2=-2i-2\sqrt{-1-i}$$
we get this using the formula for a quadratic equation of the form
$$x^2+px+q=0$$ which has the Solutions
$$x_1=-\frac{p}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q}$$
or
$$x_2=-\frac{p}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q}$$

Comment: Perhaps you should mention **how**  you did arrive at those results: quadratic equation's roots' formula

Comment: i have wrote this with the formula, thank you for the hint

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: Is there a way of writing $z=-2i±2i*sqrt(i+1)$ as $z = a + bi$

Comment: yes there is a way, where should i write this?